# DBPATH, LOGPATH and STORAGEPATH

Tags: db2, storage, db2-luw, physical-design

Assuming that there are only two available paths, say /log and /data. Would it be better to set DBPATH to /log or /data. I.e.

```
CREATE DATABASE WHATEVER  
AUTOMATIC STORAGE YES
ON /data DBPATH ON /log;
UPDATE DB CFG WHATEVER USING newlogpath /log;
```

or

```
CREATE DATABASE WHATEVER  
AUTOMATIC STORAGE YES
ON /data DBPATH ON /data;
UPDATE DB CFG WHATEVER USING newlogpath /log;
```

I noticed the other day a system that used /data for both DBPATH and tablespace storage, and I'm wondering whether /log would have been a better choice for DBPATH?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It almost certainly doesn't really matter.

The only significant I/O going to files in the database path would be to the recovery history file (and even that isn't much).

Considering that DB2 uses the first storage path by default if you do not specify `DBPATH ON`, I would put it on `/data` if that was the only choice.

My SOP is to keep DBPATH in the instance owner home directory.  This is obviously another important location and perhaps makes more sense than the other two locations.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen recommendations on separating DBPATH and tablespaces, but I assume this has more to do with DBPATH holding the transaction logs by default (as pointed out by @mustaccio in a now removed answer).